# Disable closed issues for editing in Redmine

Tags: redmine

I want to disable comments (or "editing issue" - the pencil button with my-redmine-server/issues/***/edit link) for closed tickets in Redmine but I failed to find how to do this. Is it possible? I tried to google the solution with no success.

Environment:
  Redmine version                2.5.2.stable
  Ruby version                   1.9.3-p484 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  3.2.19

Comment: I've asked something similar before but couldn't get any answer. This feature has yet to be added: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23430706/320120

Comment: @EnmosProje , I've created a ticket on official redmine website with similar question, it was closed with the comment "You can change on setting page.", but there is no such option - [link](http://www.redmine.org/issues/18382). On the forum I haven't got an answer.

Comment: You should try their forums as Toshi MARUYAMA on Redmine has suggested but if you check my question in SO, you'll see that there isn't a setting which accomplishes what we both want. Redmine hasn't got such a complex embedded "Rules Engine". I haven't solved my problem yet but we learned to use the system as it is by adjusting our processes to it. Maybe a plugin which solves this problem already exists but I couldn't find one at the time.

Comment: @EnmosProje, I also asked on their forum, but I haven't got an answer - [forum](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/44743). So, I'm still looking for a plugin, and I will answer here if I get it :)